# PGAUDIT on RHEL 7.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-extensions

I have download PostGreSQL 9.6 and pgaudit 9.6 from my RHEL repository.  I have installed the rpm.

How to I verify it is installed correctly?  I have not been able to find good directions.

It seems that I should perhaps

```
psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit"
```

After install, but I am not sure.  When I do try this, I get

```
-bash-4.2$  psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit;"
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.6/share/extension/pgaudit.control": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you have to have

```
"shared_preload_libraries='pgaudit'"
```

in the configuration file.  Then, this command verifies it is working

```
SHOW shared_preload_libraries;
```